# React Native load state from Async storage on start

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setstate, asyncstorage

State "reminders" saved to AsyncStorage with key "reminders".
Now I need to load "reminders" from AsyncStorage with key "reminders" every time App started.
And then show it in a FlatList.

How I can do this?

```
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';

function Reminders() {

  // REMINDERS
  const [reminders, setReminders] = useState([
    {day: 'MON', time: new Date(), status: true},
    {day: 'TUE', time: new Date(), status: true},
    {day: 'WED', time: new Date(), status: true}
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={reminders}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => (
          <View><Text>{item}</Text></View>
  );
}
export default Reminders;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the hook `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(readReminders, []);

function readReminders() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('reminders').then(value=> setReminders(value));
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to useEffect.
Can you show me where to place your code into mine?

Comment: Yes, put my code before your return and include useEffect in the react import, making it like this:

import React, {useState, useEffect, Component} from 'react';